# UISearchBar tinted like Contacts

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uisearchbar

The `UISearchBar` in my `UITableView` header is the strong color.

The `TableSearch` uses the more subtle code, but I'm not sure how it's doing it. I've looked at the TableSearch example code. Specifically, I don't see `tintColor` being used anywhere in this example. I don't see opacity or alpha used, either.

How does the `TableSearch` example do this? Can anyone explain it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007529-CH3-SW8), there is a `tintColor` property on the `UISearchBar` class.

In the [TableSearch example](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/TableSearch/) the search bar is defined and loaded in the MainView.xib. If you want to change its tintColor or style, just do it in the xib and it will be loaded into the application.

Comment: What I'm trying to figure out is how Apple's code manages it. There's no tintColor in the sample code anywhere.

Comment: There isn't, because the bar in the example does not have a tintColor - it uses the default (=nil) and renders the bar with the style defined (`UIBarStyle barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault`).

Comment: I guess the answer, then, is that the table view automatically tints the attached search bar? Good enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the UISearchBar to any color you like using:

```
self.mySearchBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:153/255.0 green:102/255.0 blue:51/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

In this example the first number in the fractions are the RGB values. Just find the RGB color you want and fill in the values here.

Answer (score 0):

I thought i'd mention that the alpha value for the tint colour does not seem to do anything. It always displays as alpha 1.0 value, and in interface builder, it does not let you adjust the opacity value.